# Babel transform imports to destructure default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

I'm trying to create a build pipeline which doesn't bundle the files together, but instead uses `<script type="module">`. This will let me just recompile files as they change without rebundling, greatly improving build times during development.

Our project uses ES6, so this is generally easy.

There is however one snag: third-party modules that only have CommonJS builds (such as react).

There are a few ways around this. For now, I have a transform that changes the import name from `react` to `/node_modules/react` and my server is smart enough to then go find the appropriate `dist` file from `node_modules` and serve it up. This all works fine.

The problem is that it gets confused when I try to do something like:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
```

That won't work how it currently is (because it gets confused by there not being a default). However, this will work:

```
import * as React from 'react';
const { Component } = React;
```

I could manually do this for all files and packages, but a) that would make it unnecessarily ugly (with Redux and other things, there are half a dozen different packages in many files we'd have to do this to and b) there are lots of files, I don't want to manually change them all.

**Is there a Babel transform plugin that can automatically make this kind of conversion?** It seems that this isn't a completely novel approach, so I'm hoping there is a plugin that'll do it for me that my Google-fu failed to find.

Comment: Who or what gets confused? You really should fix that, not use the ugly style everywhere.

Comment: "It" is Chrome in this case. When using `type="module"` it tries to use a ESM import, but for the CJS modules, they don't have a "default" export it detects so it throws an error "module 'blahblah' does not have a default export". Can't really fix that directly.

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports CJS modules at all, it should throw an error about not having a named export "`Component`" as well. I think you actually should do `import 'react'; const { Component } = React;`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrapping it up myself into something which will gather those up then `export default` them. Having to do some magic tricks... hopefully it'll work. =p

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working. I ended up having to write my own Babel plugin which makes the changes that I was looking for. Basically, for the different versions of the `import` statement, it changes it around in order to work better with UMD and CJS modules.

For example, something like this:

```
import A, { a, b, c } from 'a';
```

was transformed into something like this:

```
import * from __babel_A from 'a';
const A = __babel_A.default && (__babel_A.default.default || __babel_A.default) || __babel_A;
const { a, b, c } = __babel_A.default || __babel_A;
```

This format came about based on the way most things export. Many (like React) would put everything into an object with it's name on either `module.exports` (if I provided a fake one) or `this` or `window`. Others ended up not grouping things together (like ReactRTE) and had its own "default", which is where the `default.default` bit came from.

In addition to this transform, when my server serves up the dist versions of the third-party files, it'd wrap them up in a way that would then let me do an `export default`. That looked like this:

```
const module = {}; 
const keys = Object.keys(this || window);
const toExport = (function __auto_wrapper() {  
  ${fileCode}

  return module.exports || Object.keys(this).reduce((r, k) => keys.includes(k) ? r : Object.assign(r, { [k]: this[k].default || this[k] }), {});
}).call(this || window);

export default Object.keys(toExport).length === 1 ? Object.entries(toExport)[0][1] : toExport;
```

Again, the different ways are based on what the different projects output. Some will use `module.exports` when given it, others won't consider `module.exports` a real thing since I (purposely) didn't initialize `export` as an object (if I did, it'd try to use `require()` which I didn't want). In my case, ReactRTE had just a CJS module instead of an UMD, so I also had to do replace on its code to replace `require('react')` and `require('react-dom')` with references to the objects on `window` instead.

This all works as I wanted (completely unbundled code loading in the browser). The only slight side-effect is that `React` and friends are all available on `window` (which they normally wouldn't be if bundled properly), but that's pretty minor.